# How can I shorten this rails cluster of querys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have cluster of querys that could become problematic.  I'd like to shorten it, but i'm not sure how to go about that.

```
  def self.exectue
    Organization.has_plan do |o|
      o.channels.each do |c|
        c.users.enabled.send_weekly_report.each do |u|
          u.in_timezone do
            WeeklyReportMailer.delay.send_report(c, u) if Time.zone.now.hour == SEND_HOUR
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

class Organization
  scope :has_plan, -> { joins(:subscription => :plan)}
end

class User
  scope :enabled, -> { where(disabled: false) }
  scope :send_weekly_report, -> { where(send_weekly_report: true) }
end

class Channel
    belongs_to :organization

    has_many :channel_users
    has_many :users, through: :channel_users
end
```

As you can see there are too many querys. How can I reduce the amount of queries?

Comment: What is `channels`? Please show us the `Channel` model. From what I see now, the is a lack of relations: `class Organization ; has_many :channels`, `class Channel ; has_many :users`, `class User ; belongs_to :channel` etc.

Comment: Sorry those relations are there, I just didn't include them to keep the code short.

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord` provides an ability to eagerly load nested models: [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#includes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes):

```
class Organization
  scope :with_users, -> { includes(channel: :user) }
end

Organization.has_plan.with_users do |o|
  o.channels.each do |c|
    c.users.enabled.send_weekly_report.each do |u|
......
```

The above will load all the channels with users within the very first query on `Organization`.

Comment: Doesn't the use of the scope on users (enabled.send_weekly_report) mean that the eager loader users aren't actually used?

Comment: I don't think so, but of course I might be mistaken. I believe that `ActiveRecord` will be able to query the `ActiveRecord::Relation` directly instead of the database (simple enough to test, but I don't have access to a shell right now)

Comment: I am personally never concerned about rails magic :) Try it yourself and if it fails to scope properly, just filter the dataset, returned by `include` scope, manually in ruby.

Comment: Btw, can't you write the `includes` a bit simpler ? Like this: `includes(channel: :user)` ?

Comment: @Mat Indeed, thank you. Friday evening is Friday evening :)